# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied in anaconda spyder for tesseract.exe

Tags: anaconda, spyder, tesseract

```
runfile('E:/python/tensorflow.py', wdir='E:/python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-c970ef5c8f56>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/python/tensorflow.py', wdir='E:/python')

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "E:/python/tensorflow.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "E:\python\tensorflow.py", line 18, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 358, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 357, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 266, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 237, in run_tesseract
    raise e

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 234, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\Harsh\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

my code

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Aug 19 15:17:41 2020

@author: Harsh
"""

import cv2
#import tesseract as te
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd= r"C:\\Users\\Harsh\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tesseract\\Library\\bin"


img = cv2.imread("sample1.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

#print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("sample1.jpg")))

cv2.imshow("Img",img)

print(text)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd` is wrong. Read pytesseract doc how to set it correctly.